# Export emails from MS Outlook 2010 to Windows Live Mail

Tags: import, export, outlook-2010

Do someone know if there is a way to export all emails from Outlook and import them into Windows Live Mail? Or to use some tools to do this?

Or if you have some advise if it is possible to do it programmatically? I can get emails into CSV from Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link provides instructions to solve your problem:
http://lookforitoverhere.com/276/outlook-2007-email-to-windows-live-mail-easy-guide/
Works for Outlook 2010 as well.
Cheers